# Passing <%=value%> in user control (.ascx)

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the ascx control in .aspx

```
<Menu:MNU ID="PMPHeaderMenu" runat="server" HiLiter="<%=h%>"></Menu:MNU>
```

in aspx.cs I have

```
  public int h = 1;
  ....
  ....
  h = 5;
```

in ascx.cs I have the HiLiter Property

```
   public string HiLiter { get; set; }
```

When I debug I get the value as <%=h%> for HiLiter when I expect it to be 5.

How will I pass the server side set value to the user control?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using c# in Web Forms to passing parameter to user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811256/using-c-sharp-in-web-forms-to-passing-parameter-to-user-control)

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1393407/5558443)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `<%=%>` for controls with `runat="server"` for setting properties, `<%=%>` is similar like Response.Write.

`<%# %>` (Data-binding expressions) can be used to fill control properties, but the control should be inside a data-binding container like  `GridView`, `DetailsView`, `FormView` and `Repeater`.

In your case you should set the value of the property from the code behind (`aspx.cs`) page like following.

```
 PMPHeaderMenu.HiLiter = h;
 this.DataBind();
```

Comment: @venkat not sure why you added this.DataBind();

Comment: The control neednot be in a databinding container like GridView, DetailsView as you mentioned. Using this.DataBind() serves the purpose.

Comment: If you assigning the property  through code behind you don't need to write  this.DataBind(); and it's also not necessary it to be a container. Issue is only with Data-binding expressions

Comment: I had to use this.DataBind() in code behind otherwise it didnot work. I am not sure why.

Comment: surprising, I tried the exact and it worked for me :)